# How can I run `done < <(curl -sL file.txt);` in older versions (1993-12-28) of ksh or update to bash?

Tags: bash, curl, ksh

I have a script that runs flawlessly on many of the servers required.  But recently it's failed on servers with old ksh versions.

Can you help me fix the offending line:

```
#!/bin/ksh
SUCCESS=0
FAILURE=0
while read IP
do
    CURL=$(curl -s -m 2 -x http://$IP -L http://icanhazip.com)
    if  [[ "${IP%%:*}" == "${CURL%%:*}" ]] ; then
        SUCCESS=$[SUCCESS+1]
        echo "$IP   ✓"
    else
        FAILURE=$[FAILURE+1]
        echo "$IP   X"
    fi
done < <(curl -sL vpn-proxy-list.txt);
echo "✓: $SUCCESS   X: $FAILURE"
```

The final line returns:

```
line 3: syntax error at line 14: `<(' unexpected
```

Unfortunately I'm unable to update ksh.

Can you help me make the `done < <(curl -sL vpn-proxy-list.txt);` portion simply work in bash? Or compatible with older versions (1993) of ksh?

Comment: Does it work if you store the output of `curl -sL vpn-proxy-list.txt` as a variable, and then pass that variable to the while loop instead?

Comment: presumably, this is on a old-line Unix, like AIX, HP, Sun? Look for ksk93 or /usr/???/dtksh. And change the #!/bin/ksh to match, of course. Good luck.

Comment: I updated the script above to better reflect my actual script. I have counters adding up within the while loop that need to be printed outside of the loop. The answers so far work well for the original question but fail when accounting for variables accessed outside the while loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't appear to be doing anything in the while body that cause trouble if it was run in a subshell, so I'd just stick with a plain pipline:

```
#!/bin/ksh

curl -sL vpn-proxy-list.txt | while read -r ip; do
    output=$(curl -s -m 2 -x "http://$ip" -L http://icanhazip.com)
    if  [[ "${ip%%:*}" == "${output%%:*}" ]]; then
        echo "$ip   Y"
    else
        echo "$ip   X"
    fi
done
```

---

Now you're asking something that breaks because you're making variable changes in a subshell, and those variables disappear when the subshell exits. A workaround: use grouping braces

```
curl -sL vpn-proxy-list.txt | {
    success=0
    failure=0
    while read -r ip; do
        output=$(curl -s -m 2 -x "http://$ip" -L http://icanhazip.com)
        if  [[ "${ip%%:*}" == "${output%%:*}" ]]; then
            echo "$ip   Y"
            let success+=1
        else
            echo "$ip   X"
            let failure+=1
        fi
    done
    echo there were $success successes
    echo there were $failure failures
}
# variables "success" and "failure" don't exist here.
```

Comment: I was able to get this to work as well, but unfortunately I'm unable to access any counters within the while loop, outside it. Can you suggest an alternative that would allow for building up some stats along the way?

Answer (score 4):

You could make use of named pipes.

```
mkfifo foobar
curl -sL vpn-proxy-list.txt > foobar &
# Maybe sleep for a while here
while read -r IP; do
  # do something here
done < foobar
rm foobar
```

Comment: Prepended with `#!/bin/ksh`?

Comment: @Ryan You could add the shebang too!

Comment: my mistake, I did not notice it was a fifo. Apologies.

Comment: Alright I got this to work, but now I'm having problems with my counters (not in the original question, but screwing up my script nevertheless).  How can I allow for counters inside of the while loop?  And printing those counters outside of the while loop?